# Modern Flickr API for Java

Tags: java, flickr

Is there any Java API for Flickr out there that is more modern than the existing ones?

- [flickrj](http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/)

  - contains full set of API methods
  - API usage tedious, no generics, type safe values, etc.
  - no updates in two years
  - no up-to-date version in maven central
- [jickr](http://jickr.org/)

  - unmaintained, incomplete, alpha

Also, as far as I can see, all of them are missing updates and are also not (with the most current version) available via maven central.

Comment: why not just using the usual RESTful services that flickr offers?... you could use a REST api to invoke those services... or SOAP for that matter?

Comment: There would be no compile-time interface to program against, meaning you'd have to do the work of programming against the API documentation without compiler level checking (or first write your own Java Interface), take care of (token) authentication, etc. yourself.

Comment: weight those things against how quickly an API becomes obsolete (flickrj), or the maintainer gets tired (jickr). Did you actually check out the restful services yet?

Comment: I only checked out the REST services via their API browser, I did not access them via code. Your argument has valid points. Especially since I just did a run down of all the API methods the site really needs (flickr is only used for a small part), there are not many. An own implementation with a limited scope is probably preferable over anything of the available options.

Comment: @Elmar, don't forget to put your own implementation on github. :)

Comment: Just saw this question again after a year: I ended up writing my own "API", as it turns out in the end I only required a small subset of commands I accessed via REST with httpcomponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that if you just get started making the calls yourself, you will end up with your own version of a framework that works just as well. This is what happened to me, although I did reference some of the code from flickrj to help me with some basic things, but after time, I ended up with my own portable library that worked excellently.